# ORACLE 19c SELECT json_object returns ORA-00932

Tags: oracle, oracle19c, ora-00932

```sql
SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
                    KEY   'Entities' 
                    VALUE '{
                             "Entities": {
                               "Formula": "FormulaHandling",
                               "Lookup_IsoUnit": "FormulaHandling",
                               "FormulaItem": "FormulaHandling"
                             }
                           }' FORMAT JSON
                  )
  FROM dual;
```

Above statement returns,

> ```
> PL/SQL: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected UDT got CHAR
> ```

Oracle version,
SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Fri Sep 8 06:53:55 2023
Version 19.3.0.0.0

No interim patches installed

If I remove `FORMAT JSON`, then there is no error.

So how could I run first SELECT statement with `FORMAT JSON`?

What is the reason for this error?

Execute SQL select
SQL query result

Comment: It seems to be a bug because it works well in 18.4...0: https://dbfiddle.uk/5xxrAYad

Comment: also works on my 19c (19.20). Probably you need to patch to newer version than a 19.2 which is 4 years old, and lots of new json functionality was added since

Comment: Oracle upgraded to 19.18 (from 19.3) solved the issues.
Thanks for the comments.